# React state always one step behind when getting cookie

Tags: reactjs, cookies

I have a component that displays the value of the email cookie in a browser, but should update if you pass a new email in the URL.

At the moment if I pass a new email in the URL I can see that the cookie has updated but the new email is not rendered on the page, only the previous one shows.

```js
import React from "react";
import Helper from "plugins/helper";

class emailField extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      cookie: ""
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.updateCookie = this.updateCookie.bind(this);
  }

  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    if (nextState.cookie !== this.state.cookie) {
      this.updateCookie();
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.updateCookie();
  }

  updateCookie() {
    const cookie = Helper.getCookie("email");
    const query = window.location.href;
    const emailUrl = query.match(/email=/g);
    if (cookie && emailUrl) this.setState({ cookie });
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    Helper.setCookie("email", e.target.value);
  }

  render() {
    const { cookie } = this.state;
    const { id } = this.props;
    return (
      <div id={id}>
        <div className="row noEmailUrl" style={{ display: "none" }}>
          <div className="col-md-2"></div>
          <div className="col-md-10">
            <input
              className="email form-control emailPrimary"
              placeholder="Please enter your email address"
              name="EMAIL_ADDRESS_"
              value={cookie}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="row emailUrl">
          <div className="col-md-8 emailAddress">
            <span className="email">{cookie}</span>
          </div>
          <div className="col-md-4 editBtn">
            <button type="button" className="changeAddress">
              Edit email
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default emailField;

emailField.defaultProps = {
  id: " "
};
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is checking the state to see if you need to update the state.

You only need to the call to `updateCookie` once as it doesn't depend on anything in the component.

Remove your `shouldComponentUpdate` override as it is unnecessary (and furthermore harmful -- it will slow down rendering and it has a side effect, which it shouldn't have).

Comment: Thank you, I have removed it but I still have the same problem. If I pass a new email in the URL it still displays the previous one, until I refresh the page again, then it updates to the new email.

Comment: What do you use for routing? ReactRouter? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

> if I pass a new email in the URL I can see that the cookie has updated
>   but the new email is not rendered on the page, only the previous one
>   shows.

I guess this means you want to load email from the URL query string, right?
But I'm a little confused because the code you provide only loads the data from the cookie.
If you want to sync the input from the URL and also save the value to Cookie, you can try something like this. 
But I think we should only need one place to save the email data (URL query string OR cookie).
Hope this can provide some help.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Cookies from "js-cookie";

const COOKIE_KEY = "email";

export default class CookieInput extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      email: this.getInitialStateFromCookie()
    };
  }

  getInitialStateFromCookie = () => {
    // if we have email in query string, then set as initial data
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    if (urlParams.has("email")) {
      const email = urlParams.get("email");
      Cookies.set(COOKIE_KEY, email);

      return email;
    }

    // otherwise, try get data from cookie
    return Cookies.get(COOKIE_KEY) || "";
  };

  handleChange = e => {
    const email = e.target.value;

    // update state, cookie & route when input change
    this.setState({ email });
    Cookies.set(COOKIE_KEY, email);
    window.history.pushState(null, null, `?email=${email}`);
  };

  render() {
    const { email } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <input value={email} onChange={this.handleChange} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```